# Mapping of /login in spring-security not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

> I am facing some problem  in spring -security whenever i clicked on
>   the submit it redirect to the below url and i got 404

```
HTTP Status 404 - for url 
localhost:8080/TestingSecurity/login
```

> I guess there is some issue in registering springsecurity filter

code for ConfigurationDefaultXml.java

```
package cms.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"cms.controller"})
@Import(value = { SecurityConfiguration.class })
public class ConfigurationDefaultXml extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspviewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(
            ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

        // Define all possible view resolvers
        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
        resolvers.add(jspviewResolver());
        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        return resolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/design/");
    }
}
```

> Code of SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package cms.config;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("abc123").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("root123").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba1").password("root123").roles("ADMIN","DBA");//dba have two roles.
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
         .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
         .and().formLogin().loginPage("/logincustom")
         .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
         .and().csrf()
         .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

    }
}
```

> SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

package cms.config;

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}
```

> code of SpringMvcInitializer.java

```
package cms.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ConfigurationDefaultXml.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" }; 
    }

}
```

> coding of form button is given below

```
 <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                            <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    <p>You have been logged out successfully.</p>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                <label class="input-group-addon" for="username"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="ssoId" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                <label class="input-group-addon" for="password"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></label> 
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}" />

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <input type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Log in">
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Check your method is post in your form

Comment: @naman : yes it is post i have include the code of form button  in the question you can see .

Comment: You aren't setting the `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.loginProcessingUrl(String)`, I'm not sure if what you have (the action on the form) is the default.  Try explicitly setting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it will not be used as the login post URL, you need to add a loginProcessingUrl for your custom login:

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/logincustom").loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
     .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer .. i changed the loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin") to loginProcessingUrl("/login") and now its working